# Unknown Entity namespace alias in Symfony by Guard authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am working on an Guard authentication with 2 separate entity managers.

Here my config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            backoffice:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_backoffice_host%'
                port:     '%database_backoffice_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_backoffice_name%'
                user:     '%database_backoffice_user%'
                password: '%database_backoffice_password%'
                charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
                CarBundle: ~
        backoffice:
            connection: backoffice
            mappings:
                BackofficeBundle: ~
```

This is my security setting

```
services:
    backoffice.form_login_authenticator:
            class: BackofficeBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
            arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder", "@doctrine.orm.backoffice_entity_manager"]
```

After the login form, the user is found and there is an redirect to my main route /backofice , but I become this error:

```
[2017-05-07 18:32:56] request.INFO: Matched route "backoffice_home". {"route":"backoffice_home","route_parameters":{"_controller":"BackofficeBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"backoffice_home"},"request_uri":"http://ip/backoffice","method":"GET"} []
[2017-05-07 18:32:56] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2017-05-07 18:32:56] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: "Unknown Entity namespace alias 'BackofficeBundle'." at /home/metahub/autotrader/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php line 271 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'BackofficeBundle'. at /home/metahub/autotrader/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php:271)"} []
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is this:

```
security:
    encoders:
            BackofficeBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    providers:
        database_users:
            entity:
                class: BackofficeBundle:User
                property: username
                manager_name: backoffice
```

We need to setup the manager "manager_name" for this Entity direct in the security settings.

Answer (score 0):

try using `auto_mapping: true`

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
                CarBundle: ~
        backoffice:
            connection: backoffice
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                BackofficeBundle: ~
```

Comment: And what exactly will that accomplish?  Have you tried it?

Comment: You cannot enable "auto_mapping" on more than one manager at the same time (found in "default" and backoffice").