# Error migrating symfony 2.8 app to symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

i am migrating an application developed in symfony 2.8 to symfony 3.4 and it is having problems when i try to authenticate. This is de dev.log file:

```
security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\sf3\\contenedores\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:92, Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException(code: 0): Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\sf3\\contenedores\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMException.php:271)"} []
```

the auth form show: `Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.`

i can't continue the revision because is mandatory that user is authenticated.

the migration was unconvensional: i create a new symfony 3.4 project, adjust a few configs params, installed a third party bundles, and copied AppBundle Directory from old app to a new one.

at this moment the application have not deprecation errors, but the authentication process is failing.
sorry for my english.

Comment: It actually looks like the problem is with the Doctrine entity namespace.  Check the doctrine.yaml and confirm AppBundle is being used as the entity namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833990/unknown-entity-namespace-alias-in-symfony-by-guard-authentication). was a bad configuration under `providers` section in `security.yml`. The property `manager_name` was missing, this must match the connection name under `entity_manager` in `config.yml`. Apparently this is new in symfony 3